# Rails eager loading relational table with only 1 piece of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

As a simplification of my problem, lets say I have a songs and an artists table:

```
songs
-----
id
name
artist_id

artists
-------
id
name
```

The majority of the time I'm querying songs and I always need the artist name attached. Would it make sense to add another column to song called artist_name so that I don't need to do .includes(:artist) eager loading?

I think my current design is the typical one but what is the most efficient one or what is the best way to handle this situation in rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

It seems database denormalization makes sense only in heavy read applications and one should profile extensively first.

Some options:

1. Add an includes to the default scope for songs
2. Denormalize artist name and use model hooks to ensure data integrity

Answer (score 0):

```
Song.find(2, :include => :artist)
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote .joins(:artist) but I meant to write .includes(:artist) which is what I'm currently doing.